# Using "display:inline-block" but my DIV is still appearing on a new line

Tags: html, css, inline, display

I have two block elements that I would like to be on the same horizontal line.  One is a FORM and the other is a DIV.

```
<div id="miningArea">
    <form id="curWorkForm">...</form>
    <div id="buttonDescription">
        To begin, click thde "Start" button.
    </div>  
</div>
```

I thought adding `display:inline-block` was the key to keeping the elements on the same line.  But when I add

```
#buttonDescription {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

My text element still appears beneath my FORM element -- https://jsfiddle.net/5j57hkLr/6/ .  How can I get that other DIV element to appear on the same line?

Comment: #curWorkForm, #buttonDescription {
    display: inline-block;}

Comment: @VXp, per my comment to Gautum, when there is a lot of text taht doesn't seem to work -- https://jsfiddle.net/5j57hkLr/16/ .  The text block goes to the next line whereas I want it to stay on the same line as the button.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5j57hkLr/77/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is a lot of text, you have to limit the width of `inline-block` elements by applying `width` settings to them which allow both elements to fit into one line, for example `width: 50%` and `width: 45%`
Otherwise they will by default expand according to the text, which will result in 100% width when there's enough text to fill a full line.

Answer (score 1):

These are the the 3 ways ways I would think about approaching this:
(Here is a your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5j57hkLr/77/) back with some changes.)

1:

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: red dashed 1px;
  /* For Testing*/
}

.style {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <form>
    <input class="style" placeholder="Enter Value" />
  </form>
  <button class="style">Submit</button>
</div>
```

2: Responsive

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

input, button {padding:10px;}
input {width: 100%;} /* replace "input" with "input , button" if you want the button to take up full with*/


.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: red dashed 1px; /*For Testing*/
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <form>
      <input class="style" placeholder="Enter Value" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <button class="style">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

3:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

#mainWrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

button,
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.formWrap {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

.btnWrap {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainWrapper">
  <div class="formWrap">
    <form>
      <input placeholder="Enter Value" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="btnWrap">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
#buttonDescription,form {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Inorder for two or more elements to be on same line, all the elements should be made **display: inline or inline blocks**

Comment: I gave this a go, but when I add more text into my text section, it starts wrapping onto the next line -- https://jsfiddle.net/5j57hkLr/16/ .

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flex for this work the code is as follows

```
.miningArea
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}
form
{
    width: 60%;
}
div
{
    width: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6wjftgf2/2/

```
#buttonDescription,form {
display: inline-block;
}
<div id="miningArea">
<form id="curWorkForm"><input placeholder="My Form"/></form>
<div id="buttonDescription">
    <button>My Button</button>
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: you only have one element in your "miningArea" DIV.  My quesiton dealt with two elements -- the form and an additional DIV that contained text.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .miningArea { 
   display: flex; 
   flex-wrap: wrap; 
 } 
 form { width: 60%; } 
 div { width: 40%; }
```

Comment: What does this do? Provide context and explanation to make your answer more helpful.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.